# Json.Net WEB API default camelCase property name but one class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a section in WebApiConfig:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = 
    new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

But there is one class, which property name I want to be intact (UPPERCASE).

Is there any way to override default transformation for a single case? I'm returning `HttpResponseMessage` from API method.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("lang/{lang}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetTranslation(TranslateLang lang)
{
    var translations = new Translate().GetLibrary()
        .Where(t => t.LangsTranslations.Any(l => l.Language == lang))
        .ToDictionary(
            l => l.Key, 
            l => l.LangsTranslations.First(x => x.Language == lang).Text
        );
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, translations);
}
```

Thx.

Comment: Try Using following attribute on field you dont want to change.
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName="LANGUAGE")]

Comment: Above attributes are part of Newtonsoft.Json if you are using it.

Comment: But Json is my default converter. I just want to override it's format in one exceptional case. And I don't want to ignore it.

Comment: Try somthing like this [JsonProperty(PropertyName="LANGUAGE")] public string Language{get; set;}

Comment: I know, that I can override PropertyName, but I want to do it the most generic way. The model came from 3-rd party service.

Comment: Btw, as you can see, I'm returning anonymous type, so no PropertyName. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

Custom `ContractResolver`

```
public class UpperCaseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public static readonly UpperCaseContractResolver Instance = new UpperCaseContractResolver();

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.PropertyName = property.PropertyName.ToUpper();
        return property;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("lang/{lang}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetTranslation(TranslateLang lang)
{
    var translations = new Translate().GetLibrary()
        .Where(t => t.LangsTranslations.Any(l => l.Language == lang))
        .ToDictionary(
            l => l.Key, 
            l => l.LangsTranslations.First(x => x.Language == lang).Text
        );

    var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
    var json = formatter.SerializerSettings;

    json.ContractResolver = new UpperCaseContractResolver();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, translations, formatter);
}
```